# <identifier> expected

Tags: java

```
class ex5{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] mas1= new int[5];
    for (int i=0;i<mas1.length ;i++ ) {
        mas1[i]=(int)(Math.random()*10);
        System.out.print(mas1[i]);
    }
}
ex5Helper test= new ex5Helper();
test.maxNum(mas1);
test.minNum(mas1);
test.avrNum(mas1);
}

class ex5Helper{
public void maxNum(int[] maxArrayEnter){
    for (int cells:maxArrayEnter) {
        int max=0;
        if(cells>max){
            max=cells;
        }
    }
System.out.println("min number is"+min);
}
public void minNum(int[] minArrayEnter){
    for (int cells:minArrayEnter) {
        int min=10;
        if(cells<min){
            min=cells;
        }
}
System.out.println("min number is"+min);
}
public void avrNum(int[] avrArrayEnter){
int count=avrArrayEnter.length;
int avr=0;

for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
    avr=avr+avrArrayEnter[i];
    avr=avr/count;
}
System.out.println("min number is"+min);
}
}
```

компилятор выдает

> ```
> ex5.java:10: error: <identifier> expected
>         test.maxNum(mas1);
>                    ^
> ex5.java:10: error: <identifier> expected
>         test.maxNum(mas1);
>                         ^
> ex5.java:11: error: <identifier> expected
>         test.minNum(mas1);
>                    ^
> ex5.java:11: error: <identifier> expected
>         test.minNum(mas1);
>                         ^
> ex5.java:12: error: <identifier> expected
>         test.avrNum(mas1);
>                    ^
> ex5.java:12: error: <identifier> expected
>         test.avrNum(mas1);
> ```

Comment: Придерживайтесь конвенций насчет имен и форматирования. Тогда ваш код будет легче читать. В частности, люди более охотно будут отвечать на ваши вопросы. Имена классов должны начинаться с большой буквы. Вместо `for (int i=0;i<mas1.length ;i++ )` лучше писать `for (int i = 0; i < mas1.length; i++)`

Comment: @m.vokhm спасибо:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В теле класса могут быть только объявления. Код должен быть внутри методов.

```
class Ex5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] mas1 = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < mas1.length; i++) {
            mas1[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
            System.out.print(mas1[i]);
        }

        ex5Helper test = new ex5Helper();
        test.maxNum(mas1);
        test.minNum(mas1);
        test.avrNum(mas1);
    }
}
```

Если бы вы соблюдали форматирование, то легко заметили бы проблему.