# Java identifier expected

Tags: java, массивы, list, arraylist, интерфейс

Чуть чуть в замешательстве. У меня есть такие конструкторы:

```
public Circle() {
    this.center = new Point(0,0);//center.getX()
    this.inline = new Point(10,0);//inline.getX()
}


public Circle(Point center, Point inline) {
    this.center = center;
    this.inline = inline;
}
```

И я хочу сделать следующее:

```
List<IShape> shapes=new ArrayList();
shapes.add(new Circle(new Point(0,0),new Point(5,5) ));
shapes.add(new Circle());
```

Circle имплементирует IShape.
Вот только при добавлении фигуры среда разработки говорит следующее:

> expected
>
> illegal start of type
>
> package shapes does not exist

Как решить эту проблему?

P.S. Добавляю файл полностью.

```
package shapesprog;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ShapesDAO {
    
        List<IShape> shapes = new ArrayList();
        shapes.add(new Circle(new Point(0,0),new Point(5,5) ));
        shapes.add(new Circle());
        shapes.add();
        
           
}
```

Comment: Где-то что-то у вас напутано, возможно со скобками. Покажите целиком файл с ошибкой.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [<identifier> expected](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1025135/204271)

Comment: Добавила, но там просто больше ничего и нет...

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ShapesDAO {

  List<IShape> shapes = new ArrayList();

  public ShapesDAO() { 
    shapes.add(new Circle(new Point(0,0),new Point(5,5) ));
    shapes.add(new Circle());
    shapes.add();
  }
       
}
```

Comment: Извините, но для чего здесь конструктор? Я же не собиралась создавать объекты этого класса в принципе...

Comment: @МарияЛинк "Я же не собиралась создавать объекты этого класса" - это из Вашего вопроса не видно. В таком случае, перед `List<IShape> shapes` не хватает `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, решила. Добавила весь код внутри класса в блок static.